How can I alias a folder (module) in Python to use it like a class with import corerec.UF_Engine?
I’m working on a Python project and I have a folder (unionizedFilterEngine) inside my corerec.engines directory that contains a class (unionizedFilterEngine). I want to import the class in such a way that I can use it with a simpler alias, like corerec.UF_Engine, instead of the full path corerec.engines.unionizedFilterEngine.
Here’s the current structure of my project:
corerec/
├── __init__.py                
├── engines/
│   ├── __init__.py            
│   ├── unionizedFilterEngine/
│   │   ├── __init__.py        
│   │   ├── filterEngine.py    # Contains the class `unionizedFilterEngine`


Current Code Example:
filterEngine.py:

class unionizedFilterEngine:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Unionized Filter Engine initialized!")

    def context(self):
        return "Context method called!"

I want to alias the unionizedFilterEngine folder/module as UF_Engine so that I can import it like this:
import corerec.UF_Engine
And then use it like:
UF_Engine.context()
I’ve tried setting up the init.py files, but I am still unable to make it work. Can anyone help me figure out how to alias the folder/module properly?
Tags: python, import, aliasing, module, class
I tries to define UF_Egnie alias in corerec.engine and earlier also defined in corerec’s init but its not working...
I am expecting :
corerec.UF_Engnie
than after I can use:
import corerec.UF_Engnie as uf
uf.blahblah()


To achieve the aliasing you want, you can modify the __init__.py files in your project to create the desired alias. Here's how you can do it:

corerec/engines/unionizedFilterEngine/init.py:
from .filterEngine import unionizedFilterEngine


corerec/engines/init.py:
from .unionizedFilterEngine import unionizedFilterEngine as UF_Engine


corerec/init.py:
from .engines import UF_Engine



With these changes, you should be able to import the unionizedFilterEngine class using the alias corerec.UF_Engine like this:
import corerec.UF_Engine

engine = corerec.UF_Engine()
print(engine.context())

This setup ensures that the unionizedFilterEngine class is accessible through the alias corerec.UF_Engine, making your imports cleaner and more intuitive.

actually the problem Is :
UnionisedFilterEngine is as folder where there are many algorithms in .py format.
I want user to just type :
from corerec.UF_Engine import algorithm123
instead :
from corerec.engine.unionizedfilterengine import algo123
